# Angular 6 change JWT token before remake request after token update

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, jwt

I'm using JWT authentication end when token is expired (the backend checks it) I have to call a refresh token API and remake the last call failed because the expired token.
I already have the Interceptor but I have to update the authentication header before make the request and I have to wait the `refreshToken` call.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const { shouldRetry } = this;
    return next.handle(request).pipe(  
      retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy({
        shouldRetry
      })),

      catchError(err => {
        //401 the token is invalid so I have to refresh it
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.auth.refreshToken().subscribe(
            (apiResult: SessionTokenResponse) => {
              this.auth.saveToken(apiResult.token);
            },
            error => this.auth.logout()
          );
          request = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.auth.getSessionToken)});
          return next.handle(request);
        }
        const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
        return throwError(error);
      }),
    )
  }
```

Is it the correct way to remake the call? How can I wait the end of `refreshToken`? Thanks

EDIT: I updated with this code that seems to be work, I'm testing it

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
const { shouldRetry } = this;
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy({
    shouldRetry
  })),

  catchError(err => {
    //401 the token is invalid so I have to refresh it
    if (err.status === 401) {
      this.auth.refreshToken().subscribe(
        (apiResult: SessionTokenResponse) => {
          this.auth.saveToken(apiResult.token);
          request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + apiResult.token) });
          next.handle(request).subscribe();
        },
        err => this.auth.logout()
      );          
    }else{
      const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
      return throwError(error);
    }
  }),
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question well, you can wait for refresh token by using  `async`
you can check access for current token or refresh it if it's invalid in `CanActivate` By the way, on each request, it'll check Access for token and no need to add additional code in `interceptor`

in auth service

```
     async isAuthenticated(){
     const response = await this.auth.refreshToken().toPromise();
     return response;
  }
```

in CanActivate

```
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.authenticated= await this.Service.isAuthenticated();
    if(this.authenticated) {
         this.auth.saveToken(apiResult.token);
         return true;
      }
    else
        this.auth.logout();
        // navigate to login

}
```

Comment: I have to wait the new token before remake the call

Comment: to undestand if the token has to be update I have to manage 401 error, in your example you update the token without this check